# Testcafe concurrency and dependent tests

Tags: concurrency, dependencies, testcafe

I would like to run Testcafe with concurrency because of the improved performance.

However I have some tests that are dependent of eachother, e.g. one test where I add a record to the database and one where I test the deletion of the same record.

In concurrency mode, the 2nd test fails because the record to delete does not exist (yet).

Is there a way to use concurrency but at the same time keep these tests together in one thread?

Regards
Joost

Comment: `quarantinemode` with `successThreshold` and `attemptLimit` might help, but then tests are marked as unstable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to create independent tests so that you can run any test at any time. It is not possible to control the order in which tests are executed.